# Angularjs ng-print dynamically generated table rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I was wondering how would I go about printing (**real print** with `ng-print` or some other way) dynamically generated table rows conditionally ? I have managed to put data into table and inserted button with `ng-show` to display `<div>` styled as button in my case I only need logic or way to go about printing row where that button is displayed. As in when button is clicked get the data from that row and print it.

Note: You can assume that all data is loaded and present in table so it is there for using.

Here is the table representation for better visualization.

```
| TH    | TH    | TH    | TH    |   TH      |
|----   |------ |------ |-----  |:-----:    |
| 1     | Info  | Info  | YES   | PRINT     |
| 2     | Info  | Info  | NO    |           |
| 3     | Info  | Info  | YES   | PRINT     |
| 4     | Info  | Info  | YES   | PRINT     |
| 5     | Info  | Info  | No    |           |
| 6     | Info  | Info  | YES   | PRINT     |
```

**Edit:** All data needs to be present in the table, but I only need to show option to print the row which has the print button on it which as i explained is shown only if YES is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same condition used on print button on `<tr>`, so `<tr ng-show="condition">`

Even better, you may don't print those rows using `<tr ng-if="condition">`

---

EDIT

[ng-print page](http://github.com/gilf/ngPrint) says:

*Use the ng-print directive on a button to indicate that it is a print button. Use the print-element-id attribute to indicate the id of the element you want to print. For example, if you want to print the whole page you can wrap it in an element with the id of myPage and set the print-element-id attribute to myPage.*


So you can give an id to your  an id and use it to identify the element to print:

`<tr id="row_#">
<button ng-print print-element-id="row_#">`

Comment: Yeah I know, but I need it to print as in open a real print dialog with data from that row for printing with real printer.

Comment: I added more info, I don't need to hide any data I only need to print the rows that have TD evaluated as YES to print. And by print I need `ng-print` or similar approach that will open print dialog.

Comment: Sadly it does not work because the button is inside the table i guess.

Comment: Try identify an external div and check if it works. If it does, then just identify all the table (or a div which contains it) and dinamicaly ng-hide all other rows

Comment: Wont work, id be super glad if i could just print the row on which is the button located... Driving me mad at the moment.

Comment: If it doesn't work neither on an external div, then your code is missing something. Are you familiar with Angular? Have you ever used external Angular plugins? Sorry if I ask, but if the library doesn't work at all, probably the error is in your code